# How to use docker-compose with podman?

Tags: fedora, rhel, docker, podman

My [system](https://fedoramagazine.org/docker-and-fedora-32/) does not provide `dockerd` anymore, but `docker-compose` requires `dockerd` in order to run

How should I migrate existing configurations (such as [this](https://github.com/big-data-europe/docker-hadoop)) which are built with docker-compose to `podman`?

Comment: This doesn’t address your question directly, but you can install `moby-engine` on Fedora 32 (as mentioned in the article you linked to).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First I’d suggest trying [podman-compose](https://github.com/containers/podman-compose), to see if it works for you.  It’s packaged and installable from the Fedora repos.

Also, as [Stephen Kitt](https://unix.stackexchange.com/users/86440/stephen-kitt) said in the comments, Fedora packages `moby-engine` which is the open source version of Docker.  It should work with docker-compose, although I’ve never tried.